# I can't call user access endpoint in piano.io

Tags: reactjs, api, endpoint

I am integrating piano.io API.
Please reference the API documents in

> [https://docs.piano.io/api/?endpoint=post~2F~2Fpublisher~2Fusers~2Fget](https://docs.piano.io/api/?endpoint=post%7E2F%7E2Fpublisher%7E2Fusers%7E2Fget)

I found the api_token from my dashboard and using the token called the endpoint(`/user/access/get`).
But it returned 401 error.

Response:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "ts": 1623177101,
    "message": "Unable to find user for given API token"
}
```

if you have experience with this API, please help me quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Piano uses two endpoints. One for USA and one for EU.

- If your piano dashboard is: https://dashboard-eu.piano.io

  You must use the https://api-eu.piano.io/api/v3/publisher endpoint.
- If your piano dashboard is: https://dashboard.piano.io/

  You must use the https://api.piano.io/api/v3/publisher endpoint.